# Contractions and ampersands check for JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to test some text for contractions and ampersands (among other things) so I wrote this regex:

```
var pattern = /^[\w&;'`<>"]+$/;
if (pattern.test(comments)) {
    $("#charlimitPanel").popup("open");
    result = false;
}
```

However, when it tests for the comments as "They're going to think you & I are nuts!" it doesn't conclude that as TRUE. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern would test for an apostrophe between two letters, or an ampersand.  It would stop at the first match.  Note there are no anchors (^ or $) because you are checking only for the presence of the characters and not the positioning.

```
var pattern = /(\w'\w)|&/;
```

Comment: You don't need `(` `)` there.

Comment: I prefer this solution as it accounts for more permutations. I ultimately ended up with this: /(\w'\w)|"|&|<|>|;/;

Comment: @occasl: Use `/\w'\w|["&<>|;]/` If you match characters in alternation, you should convert them into character class. Character class is more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern doesn't allow `' '` (space) or `'!'`, both of which appear in the input string. Try

```
var pattern = /^[\w&;'`<>"\s!]+$/;
```